# Can I run Samsung apps (app market from Samsung) without a SIM and mobile connection?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-kies, sim-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy S with Android 2.2.

I have read that now there is a "Kies" app available from Samsung which would allow to upgrade the OS on the phone without connecting it with the USB cable to another computer.

That article said I have to install it through the "Samsung apps" app. So I started it, but it said it won't work without a SIM card.

But I intended to use only WiFi, I don't need the SIM card and the mobile connection.

Why this problem? Is it solvable (without a SIM card)?

Comment: Can you give a link to the source that says you can update the phone over the air with Kies? It's not supposed to be possible with Android versions prior to 2.3.x (can't remember exactly)

Comment: @onik Yes, what I read sounded similar to what you say. And I didn't read any "success strories" with Android 2.2. But I supposed one could try to somehow get Kies on Android 2.2 and then use it, although officially Kies is only for Android 2.3.x.

Comment: I've never seen Kies on Android, and it's not found on Samsung's update pages or Samsung Apps website. The only possibilities officially supported are FOTA (Firmware Over-the-Air, on newer Android versions) and Kies on PC.

Comment: @onik: Now I think I might have been mistaken about this...

Answer (score 3):

No, the Samsung apps market won't start without a SIM card, because the card is used to determine the country of the user.

There is an App called "Kies Air" which allows you to connect your device to the Kies App installed on your PC over WiFi. But I doubt that you are able to upgrade the OS this way. It's more meant for synchronization (calendar, email, ...) use.

IMHO you need a USB cable to update the SGS, either with Kies or [Odin](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odin)/[Heimdall](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heimdall).

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no Kies app for Android, as @onik notes in the comments.

I was mistaken probably when I thought that there is one.

Answer (score -1):

Im able to get Samsung apps market app on my phone with no sim card it can etect country via wifi, works on Galaxy s3

Comment: How does this answer the question?